# Copying only modified files from one host to another

Tags: linux, copy-paste

I was using scp to copy files from one host to another host. But presently it is copying all the files and overwriting the existing files.

How do I copy only those files which are modified.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use rsync - look at the man page for more info: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `scp` cannot do this but `rsync` can by using parameter `-a`. It also provides various other interesting options. I always try to prefer `rsync` over `scp` but that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -rut /your/diectory user@targetip:/target/location
```

It may help.